# Blocking read until specified number bytes arrived

Tags: c, linux, file-io

I have a requirement of waiting using "read" until a buffer is full on an audio codec device. For make it easier, lets take similar example of:

```
 fd= read(fileno(stdin), &buf, 10);
```

How can I return from the read when I type 10 characters in stdin? (I hope if this is success, I can wait on codec until specified bytes of data is arrived).

The above example needs an "Enter Key" from console, where as I want "read" to unblock only when desired bytes of data is arrived.

EDIT: Requirement is waiting using a *single* "read" till specified bytes are arrived.

Comment: Except that example is *not* that similar.

Comment: Manipulating a console is very different from simply reading from stdin.  The tty doesn't send anything to the program until you hit return unless you put the tty in raw mode.  If your question is about reading from a device, you will only confuse things if you worry about a keyboard.

Comment: So it means I need to check how my codec device behaves on "read". The blocking is a property of the underlying device and not the property of the "read" system call. that is what you mean?

Comment: look at `termios` - it's a HUGE subject, but great fun once you get it working

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about this:

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 10
char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

/* ... */

size_t total_read = 0;
size_t total_left = BUFFER_SIZE;  /* The total size of the buffer */
char *buffer_pointer = buffer;    /* buffer is where to store the data */
while (total_left > 0)
{
    ssize_t current = read(STDIN_FILENO, buffer_pointer, total_left);
    if (current <= 0)
    {
        /* Error or end of file */
        if (current < 0)
            perror("read");  /* Error! */
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        total_read += current;     /* We have read some more data */
        total_left -= current;     /* Less data left to read */
        buffer_pointer += current; /* So we don't read over already read data */
    }
}

printf("Received %ld characters\n", total_read);
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < total_read; i++)
    printf("Character #%d: '%c'\n", i, buffer[i]);
```

Beware that this will block your program until all data is read. The amount of characters read may be less than everything, because there might be an error or the user pressed `CTRL-D` (end of file).

Also note that the STDIN_FILE file-descriptor is most likely connected to a tty, which means it might be buffered, so doesn't return data until newline, and that you might have to make the tty unbuffered.

**Edit** 
To make sure the tty connected to stdin is unbuffered, use the following code:

```
#include <termios.h>

/* ... */

/* Somewhere before reading from stdin... */
struct termios tty_settings;

tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &tty_settings);
tty_settings.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;
tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &tty_settings);
```

For more information about the `tcsetattr` function and the `ICANON` flag, check the manual page for `tcsetattr`.

Comment: Thanks. But it doesnt resolve my ultimate purpose of blocking at single read until specified bytes are read. I think as William Pursell  pointed out, it is a device dependent property.

Comment: @LunarMushrooms It's what you initialize the `total_left` variable to. If you initialize it to 10 (as in my example), the reading loop will block until you have read 10 bytes. If `total_read` is less than the requested number of bytes, then it's either an error or an EOF.

Comment: that is the case with std in/out. But when you read from special device, like soundcard, it will return before given bytes completely read. It is device dependent. It is about how you wrote the device driver.

Comment: @LunarMushrooms That's why I put it in a _loop_.

Comment: my requirement was blocking behavior for N bytes. Not a way to read data.

Comment: So you want to block until there is N data to read, but not read _until_ that moment? Unfortunately that's impossible.

Comment: @ Joachim Pileborg , exactly. Thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 1):

```
do {ioctl(fd_port, FIONREAD, &bytes);} while (bytes < size);
```

May help, before issuing a `read()`.

Comment: Did you mean I_NREAD? This is an interesting solution but it doesn't seem to improve on the earlier one by "Some programmer dude" - the only reason I can think to want to avoid issuing multiple read() system calls is to avoid the system call overhead, but ioctl() is also a system call...